# I need to consume a WS SOAP JAVA in a client C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, ws-security

I need to consume this WS "https://secure.aduana.gov.py/test/wsdl/tere2/serviciotere"

And I have to develop a client in C # asp.net for consuming the WS.

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but don't correctly interpret the wsdl to setting "web.config" the "svcutil" utility.

This is an example of the SOAP REQUEST

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <wsse:Security
   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
   soap:mustUnderstand="1">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
    wsu:Id="X509-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205332812">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
   </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205332510">
    <wsu:Created>2016-05-26T19:47:33.324Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2016-05-26T19:52:33.324Z</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
   <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    Id="EK-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205333916">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <ds:X509Data>
       <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        <ds:X509IssuerName>C=SE,O=EJBCA Sample,CN=AdminCA1
        </ds:X509IssuerName>
        <ds:X509SerialNumber>7464959933048038457</ds:X509SerialNumber>
       </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
      </ds:X509Data>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
     <xenc:CipherValue>vbTQmpPY+JTbUR07dsRtjaUH/wIKBAGeOm0cwseszRgnMLFgAzfAlA+PdaSMD/gX9s1CinDY4g5U9hzajANZBLiWErYBT7a4IwyxcGq64y1FL2cpu5TREJZ3bd2Ur1iEvKSCoggq6Lz5Xo6g31cg/QwcUMfn47LhoSy8V5ytROs=
     </xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:ReferenceList>
     <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205333917" />
     <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205334118" />
    </xenc:ReferenceList>
   </xenc:EncryptedKey>
   <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    Id="ED-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205334118" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod
     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
      xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
      xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
      wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
      <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205333916" />
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
     <xenc:CipherValue>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
     </xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
   </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <soap:Body
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  wsu:Id="_3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205332511">
  <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
   Id="ED-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205333917" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
   <xenc:EncryptionMethod
    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
     xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
     wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
     <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-3324D992377F0E3E1B146429205333916" />
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>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
    </xenc:CipherValue>
   </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedData>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is an example of the RESPONSE

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security
   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
   soap:mustUnderstand="1">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
    wsu:Id="8FE28A30642EFF24D21464292054078115">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
   </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-89">
    <wsu:Created>2016-05-26T19:47:34.071Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2016-05-26T19:52:34.071Z</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
   <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    Id="EK-8FE28A30642EFF24D21464292054078114">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:Reference URI="#8FE28A30642EFF24D21464292054078115"
       ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
     <xenc:CipherValue>ZUSKlU/c2gySvLNKQhwwcMpM96rEQuMzC7DgFYQZZEbdLYke12Zh6uUncXlR9Hw+X/7wmMmWUCITacvsC3L+GPo/JS2xavKodM/5TvYR87wgTP0H4eMovPYkGUrvwyryx4fC6PR1EXCcLZSlukKDUtcuxazmc0wyMwLXQyf+mAs=
     </xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:ReferenceList>
     <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-91" />
     <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-92" />
    </xenc:ReferenceList>
   </xenc:EncryptedKey>
   <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    Id="ED-92" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod
     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
      xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
      xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
      wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
      <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-8FE28A30642EFF24D21464292054078114" />
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
     <xenc:CipherValue>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
     </xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
   </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  wsu:Id="Id-1407553777">
  <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
   Id="ED-91" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
   <xenc:EncryptionMethod
    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
     xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
     wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
     <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-8FE28A30642EFF24D21464292054078114" />
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>nrvPaLHVG6FrD3c5T/qLxB4emykURr8SxECH4X5vkynqQV4nFKwFXUbdRI/ZvF7crhR5b+Sh12AATZ+1NGsHaaNcQRSWBwAYKxpI1s5jEbLaZifn+m5n+yyU77SlIc1MoG/IE64mrGxX11hqzMKitqLo9W1gUAIKYnin5yaOONVLEdULT21yigoksM7Mo+TxC1nsx2MyayBEifuFZYMClDr03u4S4dTzRs5R4j9/FQLfOTHmXf01hVVoHNTDqcdYi/4kgDqDfom42cIrWUY+/vG/IW3ZoyRa2zGubBQh2aSMyKzTPPIKYV/YK640kEoaCyYqvCeWLl2DHApzTJHWWoTfZmuELfkX
    </xenc:CipherValue>
   </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedData>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can generate a wsdl from the sample input message?
some help?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project in the Solution Explorer then Add -> Add Service reference the put the address of the wsdl in the Add Service Reference window

[image]

The you can call the service using the different classes and methods present in the auto-generated namespace (in the example above it's `MyService`).

Comment: sorry Nasreddine, the correct link is https://secure.aduana.gov.py/test/wsdl/tere2/serviciotere

Comment: The process remains the same. Just copy the correct link and Visual Studio will generate a client for this web service automatically for you.

Comment: this call the "svcutil" utility, see the warnings